# amsart margin control

Tags: margins, amsart

I am using amsart to typeset some documents. However, the default margins are very large and I would like to change them without altering anything else about amsart. Is there a way to reset just the margins to 1" all the way around? Right now it is much more.

Comment: `geometry` package.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here? Could you explain just a bit more? Thanks

Comment: Just checked out geometry. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

The `amsart` class has its own method for setting some page parameters. Don't use the `geometry` package with it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for text filler

\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hah. I didn't know that.  What goes wrong?

Comment: @JPi For instance that your paper might get rejected.

Comment: so your concern is about using the geometry package with the amsart class if you're intending to submit to one of the ams journals, not about a package conflict? Then perhaps your answer should reflect that.

Comment: @JPi I said “don't use”, not that the package is incompatible.

Comment: That's true, but I inferred (incorrectly) from your answer that there is a conflict.  I use amsart with geometry all the time and don't submit to ams journals, so why shouldn't I use geometry?

Answer (score 3):

Adjust margins as you see fit.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```